# Please try to help us all to ‘see more clearly now’ the great teaching of Advaita Vedanta - ‘Sat cit ananda’

Tags: adi-shankaracharya

‘Sat cit ananda’ meaning, as translated by Warwick Jessup, in his book translating a Shankara teaching 'The Eternal Way' is ‘being-consciousness-bliss’. Jessup is a life-long student of Sanskrit and Head of Sanskrit in a London School.

PROBLEM/s There appears to be widespread agreement on the second and third parts i.e ‘consciousness and ‘bliss’ - but the first of the first of the three constituent parts has at least 4 translations. To ‘being’ we can add as alternatives from other translations ‘truth’ ‘reality’ and ‘existence’.

My first tentative solution is to say that since being, truth, and existence are all inherent in ‘reality’ the first of the constituent parts should be reality - or even ‘ultimate reality’
Wider questions

Is sat-cit-ananda intended as a description of a causative, step-by-step sequence?

Is sat-cit-ananda simply three essential developments within each of us, all of which are needed to reach a certain level before awakening occurs.

Comment: No,Sat is not truth which is Satya in sanskrit i.e. Sat+Ayan(time dependent). Sat means something independent of time i.e. Self or Aatma or soul or spirit(read gita for understanding better).Knowledge of spirit is what spirituality all about. Ananda means bliss,every living being on earth is seeking eternal bliss in senses, ego like food,territory etc.,. but fails.Now an animal can never refrain from natural instincts due to lack of intellect and introspection,but a human can.Modern hindu monks are called Swami _Ananda. Swami means knower of self/Swayam and Ananda means finder of eternal bliss